Reading xls file from Japan METI website using Python
I want to access xls sheets on METI's website. But none of the usual methods work. Taking this webpage:
https://www.enecho.meti.go.jp/statistics/petroleum_and_lpgas/pl007/results.html
and this file
https://www.enecho.meti.go.jp/statistics/petroleum_and_lpgas/pl007/xls/240724s5.xls
using Pandas read_excel, or selenium to get the link, or urllib.request.urlretrieve all fail. There is no error message, but the code just runs and runs without getting the file. The problem happens for METI's statistics for industrial production and retail sales.
Is there another method that will work?

The problem comes from the fact that your request is rejected because it does not provide any HTTPS header, making pandas hang indefinitely.
Pandas read_excel has a storage_options parameter you can use to provide extra options such as an HTTPS header, but it failed nonetheless when I tried.
So I suggest using the following helper function instead, which:

gets the Excel file with the Requests package
writes the file to memory (instead of saving an intermediate file on the hard drive) using Python standard library io module
reads it with Pandas after 'pip installing' xlrd module (because the file you are trying to read is an old xls file)
returns a dataframe

from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd
import requests


def helper(url: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    response = requests.request(
        "GET",
        url,
        allow_redirects=True,
        headers={
            "Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
            "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
            "Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        },
        timeout=15,
    )
    f = BytesIO()
    f.write(response.content)
    return pd.read_excel(f)

Then:
df = helper(
    "https://www.enecho.meti.go.jp/statistics/petroleum_and_lpgas/pl007/xls/240731.xls"
)

print(df.head())

Outputs:
   Unnamed: 0           石油製品小売市況調査 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5  ... Unnamed: 10 Unnamed: 11 Unnamed: 12 Unnamed: 13 Unnamed: 14 Unnamed: 15
0         NaN  2024-07-31 00:00:00        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1         NaN                  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2         NaN                  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3         NaN                  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
4         NaN          現金価格（消費税込み）        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN

[5 rows x 16 columns]


Using selenium to read the page also hangs indefinitely. Is there something particular about the page that causes that result?

I could be mistaken, but I don't think so. Rather the way this site handles incoming connections. Cheers.
